# It is known that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}h(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}j(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{h(x)}{j(x)}=2$. Find b

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $h$ and $j$ be two functions of domain $\mathbb{R}$.
> It is known that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}h(x)=0$,
> $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}j(x)=b$ and
> $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{h(x)}{j(x)}=2$.
>
> Only one of the following values can be $b$. Which one?
>
> a)0 $\\$
>
> b)1
>
> c)2
>
> d)$+\infty$

$\\$

I know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x)}$

So I get:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{h(x)}{j(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} h(x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} j(x)} = \frac{0}{b}$$

But how does this equal two? My book says the solution is zero. Is this because L'Hôpital's rule is applied? Because if the answer is zero, then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{h(x)}{j(x)}  = \frac{0}{0}$$ which seems a good candidate for L'Hôpital's rule.

In short, my question is why is the right answer zero?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53453/discussion-on-question-by-silenceonthewire-it-is-known-that-lim-x-rightarrow1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to 1}h(x)/j(x)=2$, it follows that both $h(x), j(x) $ are non-zero in some deleted neighborhood of $x=1$. Now use algebra of limits to get $$\lim_{x\to 1}j(x)= \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{h(x)}{h(x)/j(x)}=\frac{0}{2}=0$$ Observe that the above algebraic manipulation works only because $h, j$ are non-zero as $x\to 1$. Also note that the above proves that the limit of $j(x) $ exists and is $0$ and hence $b=0$.

It is better to use algebra of limits rather than trying to use intuition and think about "what if $b\neq 0$". Such arguments while correct are indirect and use the assumption that limit of $j$ exists (this is given in question BTW). If this assumption is not given then such arguments can not be made. Thus to sum up, *rules of algebra of limits are much more useful and powerful than most beginners think they are.*